# How to change textsize of minute digit of android clock

Tags: java, android, textview, simpledateformat

I want to change the hour textsize to 25.0dip and minute textsize to 18.0dip of time.

I am using SimpleDateFormat to get the current time. But when i change the textsize whole textsize get changed to same. I want to change the sizes seprately.

Comment: put two different 'textView' one for time and one for seconds, now define their text sizes accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You need to create two different TextView one for hours with textSize of 25sp and one for minutes with a textSize of 18sp. Then put them in your xml one next to the other.

Layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.gohidoc.realmtest.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/hours"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:text="18:"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/minutes"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:text="25"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Code in your activity :

```
private TextView hours, minutes;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    hours = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hours);
    minutes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.minutes);

    this.hours.setText(YOUR HOURS);
    this.minutes.setText(YOUR MINUTES);
```

Answer (score 0):

### There are 2 ways you can achieve this

- Use **Spannable Strings** to assign relative textsize **in Code** - SIngle TextView Solution
- Use **TextSize property** of textView to assign relative textsize **in Layout** file -Double TextView Solution

Result will be same :-

[image]

Global decleration

```
private TextView spannableTextView;
private TextView hourTextView;
private TextView minuteTextView;
```

Getting views

```
    // Single TextView with spannable string
    spannableTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    // Two TextView solution
    hourTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewHour);
    minuteTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewMinute);
```

This method demonstrate both ways

```
public void updateTime() {

    // WITH SPANNABLE STRING
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    SpannableString span = new SpannableString(
            calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + "H" + calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + "M");

    // span.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.75f), 2, 3, 0);
    span.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.72f), 3, 6, 0);

    spannableTextView.setText(span);

    // WITHOUT SPANNABLE STRING

    hourTextView.setText(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + "H");

    minuteTextView.setText(calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + "M");

}
```

Layout file

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="By spannable string in Code"
    android:textColor="#0F0"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

 <TextView
     android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="By TextSize in XML"
    android:textColor="#0F0"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewHour"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewMinute"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Now you can pick which way you want to do it.**